# Where does the expectation value of $x$ formula come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, observables

I want to understand precisely where the formula for the expectation value of $x$ comes from (in QM):
$$\langle x\rangle=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi ^*x\psi dx $$

I know that an expectation value (in statistics) is just the sum of the products of the possible values $f(x)$ times their probabilities $\rho (x)$:
$$\langle f(x)\rangle=\int f(x) \rho (x)dx $$
Since in QM mechanics the probability is given by $|\psi|^2 $, the expectation value of $f(x)$ would be:
$$\langle f(x)\rangle=\int f(x) |\psi|^2dx=\int f(x)\psi^*\psi dx$$
But this differs from the form above. If $f(x)$ was Hermitian I could use the property of Hermitian operators to "move it" into the position that it should be, but since it is not necessarily Hermitian, I don't know how to explain this difference, or how to solve it.
I have consulted Griffith's QM and also online, but I cannot find an answer.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your question is actually about. Where do you want to "move" $f(x)$ to?

Comment: $x$ in all RHSs is just an integration variable

Comment: I want the f(x) to be between the "psi"s. Because while I could move the x, if the operator were, for example, the momentum operator, then I don't think that I could just move it, since it would be acting on the product of the "psi"s

Comment: @NickHeumann maybe instead your question should be why $\langle \hat{A}\rangle = \int dx \; \psi^* \hat{A} \psi$ in general then?

Comment: The momentum operator is _not_ $-i\partial_x$ is I think the confusion? That's a position space representation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299286/why-does-the-expectation-value-of-an-operator-a-take-the-form-langle-a-ran?rq=1

Comment: Check also this: "general expectation value in QM" https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/757441/226902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, the expectation value of an observable $\hat{O}$ in a state $|\Psi\rangle$ is defined by $$ \langle \Psi|\hat{O}|\Psi\rangle \quad . $$

In your case the observable is the position operator with $\hat{x}\, |x\rangle= x\, |x\rangle$ and $\langle x|x'\rangle = \delta(x-x')$. We can write its expectation value, by making use of the relation $1 = \int \mathrm{d}x\, |x\rangle\langle x|$, as (here in 1D)

$$ \langle \Psi|\hat{x}|\Psi\rangle  = \int\mathrm{d}x \int\mathrm{d}x'\, \langle \Psi|x\rangle\langle x| \hat{x}|x'\rangle\langle x'|\Psi\rangle \quad, $$

which reduces to
$$\langle \Psi|\hat{x}|\Psi\rangle  = \int \mathrm{d}x\, \Psi^*(x)\, x \, \Psi(x) =\int \mathrm{d}x\, x\, |\Psi(x)|^ 2  \quad ,$$
where we have defined $\langle x|\Psi\rangle \equiv \Psi(x)$.

**Edit**: As OP is asking also for the case of the momentum operator: We can make similar arguments here and find
$$\langle \Psi|\hat{p}|\Psi\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}p\,p\, |\Psi(p)|^2\ \quad. $$

**Edit 2**: The above expectation value can also be carried out in the $x$-representation by using the fact that $\langle x|\hat{p}|\Psi\rangle = -i\hbar\, \partial_x \Psi(x)$:
$$ \langle \Psi|\hat{p}|\Psi\rangle=  -i\hbar \int \mathrm{d}x\, \Psi^*(x)\, \partial_x \Psi(x) \quad . $$

Comment: You don't need to insert two $x$-unity operators. One should be sufficient.

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the integrals, everything is a scalar, you can rearrange terms as you wish. It's a bit hard to see because you omitted the $x$-dependence of $\psi$. It really is
$$\int \psi^*(x)\,x\,\psi(x) dx$$
where $\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$, which clearly is a complex scalar variable, so swap stuff around any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an operator $f$ and a state
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) = \sum _n c_n \psi_n(x)
\end{equation}
with $\psi_n(x)$ being eigenfunctions of $f$. Then you get
\begin{equation}
f \psi(x) = \sum _n c_n f_n \psi_n
\end{equation}
According to your (statistical) formula
\begin{equation}
\langle f \rangle = \sum _n  f_n P_n,
\end{equation}
where $P_n$ is the probability of finding the system in the state $\psi_n(x)$, which is given by
\begin{equation}
P_n = |c_n|^2.
\end{equation}
As a result you get
\begin{equation}
\langle f \rangle =\sum _n  f_n |c_n|^2 =
\int dx \, \psi^*(x)f\psi(x)
\end{equation}