# Expectation value of position derivative of $V(x$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability

In one of the proofs of Ehrenfest theorem, at the last step claims that
$\int \frac{dV}{dx}$$(|\psi^2|)$dx is equal to the expectation value of $\frac{dV}{dx}$. Now according to my understanding of basic quantum physics, $|\psi^2|$ denotes the probability of a particle to exist at a particular position, which does not correlate to the probability of
$\frac{dV}{dx}$ attaining a particle value, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the expectation value of an operator $A$ take the form $\langle A\,\rangle=\int{\psi^* (x) A(x) \psi (x) dx}$ in QM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299286/)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is an observable of a particle on a line, with state $\psi$. The probability of finding the particle in the infinitesimal interval $dx$ is $|\psi|^2dx$. The value of the observable at point $x$ is $A(x)$.

The average value of $A$ is then the "sum" of the value $A(x)$ times the probability that the particle being in $dx$. The sum is replaced by an integral because $x$ is a continuous variable, and you get $\langle A\rangle = \int A(x) |\psi|^{2}dx$, which reproduces your quoted expression.

Comment: Im really not that familiar with dirac notation, I was hoping you could explain in a much more intuitive way.

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: @Llawliet One additional detail if you're familiar with basic probability math: this is what mathematicians call the *expected value* of the random variable A (which, physically speaking, can be any observable).

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist 'The average value of A
 is then the "sum" of the value A(x)
 times the probability that the particle being in dx', From my understanding we should multiply the value of A(x) with the probability of that value occurring, I fail to understand why that probability corelates with the probability of the particle being in dx?

Comment: The observable is evaluated at a point $x$, for example, the potential at a point has value $V(x)$. The probability of the particle being in $dx$ will correspond to the probability of the potential having the value $V(x)$.

Comment: @Llawliet This, indeed, is a non-trivial thing, IMHO. And you should've pointed this out before. But for starters, see e.g. the answer by the user Gold.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I indeed understand it mathematically proven, but I just cant make out any physical reasoning for it  why should we multiply the value of A(x) with the probability of that value occurring for it to give the expectation value

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho(x)$ be a probability distribution of some random variable $X$ defined on the real line. In that case, the probability for $X$ to attain values in $[a,b]$ is given by the integral

$$P(X\in [a,b])=\int_{a}^b\rho(x)dx.\tag{1}$$

If $f(x)$ is some function, the mean value of $f(X)$ is then *defined* to be $$\langle f(X)\rangle\equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\rho(x)dx\tag{2}.$$

In Quantum Mechanics, if $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ is the position space wavefunction of a particle in one-dimension, the probability distribution for the position random variable is, by the QM postulates, $\rho(x)=|\psi(x)|^2$.

As such, given any function of the position operator, say $f(X)$, the corresponding mean value is given by $$\langle f(X)\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)|\psi(x)|^2dx\tag{3},$$

in accordance to (2). Your question considers the particular case $f(x)=V'(x)$. While I have explained this in connection to standard random variables, equation (3) can also be derived just in QM. In that case, recall that if $X$ is the position operator and $|x\rangle$ its eigenvalue basis, a function $f(x)$ applied to $X$ is *defined* to be the operator $f(X)$ that obeys $$f(X)|x\rangle= f(x)|x\rangle\tag{4}.$$

In that case, we evaluate $\langle f(X)\rangle$ in a state $|\psi\rangle$:

$$\langle f(X)\rangle = \langle \psi|f(X)|\psi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \langle \psi|f(X)|x\rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle\tag{5},$$

where we just used completeness of the basis. Now use (4) and recognize $\langle x|\psi\rangle = \psi(x)$ and $\langle \psi|x\rangle=\psi^\ast(x)$ so that

$$\langle f(X)\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx f(x)\langle \psi|x\rangle \langle x|\psi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)|\psi(x)|^2dx\tag{6}.$$